# Pagination range issue in active admin on last page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, activeadmin, will-paginate, kaminari

I have the issue in  active-admin pagination,
Ex: suppose i have **100** records in my database, and  **per_page = 30**
then the following issue is arise.

on last page **Displaying 51-60 of 100 in total  << First << Prev 1 2 3  4 last>>**

**Second Last page display range correct**

[image: Second Last page display range correct]

**last page display range incorrect**

[image: last page display range incorrect]

Any solution.?
Thanks in Advance.